# Running two .py files in cmd via a .bat?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, arcpy

**EDIT2:** Stress tested the fix, it still failed after creating near 1TB of intermediary files. Changed .py code to delete intermediary files after performing necessary processes. Stress test succeeded after this change. Original issues likely to do with memory. Still no way of proving.

**EDIT:** I'm still not sure whether or not it was a memory issue. However I got the full process to run via .bat by breaking up the second script into 4 additional .py files and running those instead of the full second script at once. Problem solved for now.

**ORIGINAL:**
I am running two .py files through cmd via a .bat file. The reason I am doing this is the first .py is an arcpy file that requires use of 32 bit python, and the second .py is a combined PCI and arcpy file that requires use of 64 bit python.

The first file runs without issue. The second file gets to a certain point, the same point every time, and I am prompted with a "python.exe has stopped working" dialog box. This point is in the middle of a for loop in the PCI section of code. I have run the PCI python in PCI's interpreter without issue. I suspect this might be related to memory issues but am uncertain, and have no idea how to check.

How do I check to see if memory issues are the problem?

.bat code below:

```
C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.5/python.exe E:/Path/CODE/file1.py
C:/Python27/ArcGISx6410.5/python.exe E:/Path/CODE/file2.py
```

Comment: The problem doesn't sound to me like it has anything to do with running the two files, one-after-the-other, in a batch file, nor with memory (since the second script doesn't start until the first finishes.

Comment: The second script ends up creating 1.5GB worth of files and holding their name/paths in lists for various processes. I'm having some success with breaking up the code into various .py files and running them sequentially via the .bat. I think I'm up to 5 files now.

Comment: To get more information about the crash you either have to run "ArcGISx6410.5/python.exe" with an attached debugger or create a dump file when it crashes to analyze offline.

Comment: How do I create a dump file? I'm pretty new to cmd.